# Monopoly Go! - Odds of picking 3 of an item before picking 3 of another

Tags: probability

Im playing an app game called Monopoly Go! and there is a "Bank Heist" round and I feel I am getting the 'highest odds pick' much higher percentage than is probable and think the game is rigged.

There are 12 items to pick from on the board (hidden): 5 Money Bags, 4 Rings and 3 coins.

An item is picked and it is removed from the pool to pick from. i.e. 12 hidden items to start, pick 1 item, it is a Ring. There are now 11 hidden items left to pick and based on knowledge, there are 5 Money Bags, 3 Rings and 3 coins left.
If you collect 3 of the same type, you win that type and the game is over.

Example: Your first 3 picks are coins: odds are 3/12 * 2/11 * 1/10.

**My question**: What are the odds that you win a Money Bag (pick 3 Money Bag items before picking 3 Rings or Coins)? What are the odds you win a Ring? a Coin?

I can figure it out myself, but I would have to go through each permutation of a win then add the probabilities up and it would take me too long. Is there a formula or an easier way?

My long way through all permutations:
5/12 * 4/11 * 3/10 + (Money Bag first 3 picks)
7/12 * 5/11 * 4/10 * 3/9 + (Money Bag in first 4 picks)
etc ....

Edit: Clarity of problem

Comment: Hi! I think the question is a bit unclear. When would you stop picking and what are exactly the outputs you want to compute the probability for?

Comment: Check out the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). It gives the probability for drawing exactly $k$ of certain group without replacement from a pool of two possible options. You should be able to modify this to suit your question

Comment: I have added for clarity, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the fact that the order of the first 5 picks doesn't matter (either we haven't won yet or it's clear which item we won) and the fact that a random 5-element subset of these 12 items contains $m$ Money Bags, $r$ Rings, and $c$ Coins with probability $\binom5m\binom4r\binom3c/\binom{12}5$ (when $m+r+c=5$).

Splitting into cases for the first 5 picks:

- 5 Money Bags (probability $1/792$): win a Money Bag
- 4 Money Bags & 1 Ring (probability $5/198$): win a Money Bag
- 4 Money Bags & 1 Coin (probability $5/264$): win a Money Bag
- 4 Rings & 1 Money Bag (probability $5/792$): win a Ring
- 4 Rings & 1 Coin (probability $1/264$): win a Ring
- 3 Money Bags & 2 Rings (probability $5/66$): win a Money Bag
- 3 Money Bags & 2 Coins (probability $5/132$): win a Money Bag
- 3 Money Bags, 1 Ring, & 1 Coin (probability $5/33$): win a Money Bag
- 3 Rings & 2 Money Bags (probability $5/99$): win a Ring
- 3 Rings & 2 Coins (probability $1/66$): win a Ring
- 3 Rings, 1 Money Bag, & 1 Coin (probability $5/66$): win a Ring
- 3 Coins & 2 Money Bags (probability $5/396$): win a Coin
- 3 Coins & 2 Rings (probability $1/132$): win a Coin
- 3 Coins, 1 Money Bag, & 1 Ring (probability $5/198$): win a Coin
- 2 Money Bags, 2 Rings, & 1 Coin (probability $5/22$):

  - next pick is a Money Bag (probability $3/7$): win a Money Bag
  - next pick is a Ring (probability $2/7$): win a Ring
  - next pick is a Coin (probability $2/7$): need to make a 7th pick
- 2 Money Bags, 2 Coins, & 1 Ring (probability $5/33$):

  - next pick is a Money Bag (probability $3/7$): win a Money Bag
  - next pick is a Ring (probability $3/7$): need to make a 7th pick
  - next pick is a Coin (probability $1/7$): win a Coin
- 2 Coins, 2 Rings, & 1 Money Bag (probability $5/44$):

  - next pick is a Money Bag (probability $4/7$): need to make a 7th pick
  - next pick is a Ring (probability $2/7$): win a Ring
  - next pick is a Coin (probability $1/7$): win a Coin

In every "need to make a 7th pick" subcase, we have picked 2 of each type, so the next pick determines what we win—a Money Bag (probability $1/2$), Ring (probability $1/3$), or Coin (probability $1/6$).

Totaling these all up:

- we win a Money Bag with probability
  $$
  \frac1{792}+\frac5{198}+\frac5{264}+\frac5{66}+\frac5{132}+\frac5{33}+\frac5{22}\frac37+\frac5{33}\frac37+\biggl(\frac5{22}\frac27+\frac5{33}\frac37+\frac5{44}\frac47\biggr)\frac12 = \frac{527}{924};
  $$
- we win a Ring with probability
  $$
  \frac5{792}+\frac1{264}+\frac5{99}+\frac1{66}+\frac5{66}+\frac5{22}\frac27+\frac5{44}\frac27+\biggl(\frac5{22}\frac27+\frac5{33}\frac37+\frac5{44}\frac47\biggr)\frac13 = \frac{145}{462};
  $$
- we win a Coin with probability
  $$
  \frac5{396}+\frac1{132}+\frac5{198}+\frac5{33}\frac17+\frac5{44}\frac17+\biggl(\frac5{22}\frac27+\frac5{33}\frac37+\frac5{44}\frac47\biggr)\frac16 = \frac{107}{924}.
  $$

For the purposes of comparison,
$$
\biggl( \frac{527}{924}, \frac{145}{462}, \frac{107}{924} \biggr) \approx ( 0.570346, 0.313853, 0.115801 ).
$$

Just for fun, I ran a simulation of the original game $100,000$ times; it yielded 57.1% Money Bags, 31.3% Rings, and 11.6% Coins, supporting the theorical calculation above.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but even in your use case of "5 Money Bags (probability 1/792): win a Money Bag", this is not a use case because as soon as you pick the first 3 Money Bags, you win a Money Bag and the game is over (no additional picking)

Comment: Let me make my claim more explicit: imagine that you change the game so that you start by picking 5 items in a row, before checking whether you have 3 of a kind yet. My claim is that this results in the exact same probabilities.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a mathematician so I had to re-read a few times to understand your statement and the process you followed. I now understand and appreciate your answer. It is concise and understandable and believe it to be correct. FYI: I think the game is rigged (or I am unlucky) as my experience is out of 138 tries: 95 Money Bag wins, 23 rings and 20 coins. (0.688, 0.166, 0.144) ... Interesting because the Ring win is actually the best win, and its about 1/2 than the expected results.

Comment: Also, I find it interesting that the total odds are very close to the "7th pick" probability (a Money Bag (probability 1/2), Ring (probability 1/3), or Coin (probability 1/6)). This is what I assumed using my "dumb/quick" math would be the total odds.

Comment: I might not be doing the statistics right, but a [chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) on the data you reported certainly seems to suggest that the game isn't picking randomly as described (at $99.9$% level).